# Django PREPEND_WWW when http:// is hardcoded into backlink

Tags: python, django

I have `PREPEND_WWW` set on my clients site at http://www.thefrostfirm.com and it works as it should to take care of naked domains, but I have run into a scenario I am unsure how to fix.  There is an article linking back to the site as http://thefrostfirm.com and it should prepend the `www` to the url but it doesn't and I am thinking its because of `http://` being hardcoded to the link.

I tried with `RedirectView` - see below; but it doesn't work

`url(r'^http://thefrostfirm$', RedirectView.as_view(url='www.thefrostfirm.com', permanent=True), name='home'),`

Any ideas would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: From looking at the Django Middleware [code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/middleware/common.py#L57-L59) for `PREPEND_WWW`, it takes care of the `http://` or `request.scheme` that is present. Maybe there is more to it. Does it work for all other URLs? What is the Django version that you are using

Comment: Django 1.10.2 and yes, it works fine in all other cases.

Comment: Since the site is LIVE already, can you point me to the page this is happening on?

Comment: sure, go to http://thefrostfirm.com and it won't prepend

Comment: Got it. So if you have access to your DNS provider you could redirect all your base requests to `www` or you can redirect it in your `htaccess` files. I will see if it can be acheived with Django. AFAIK Django will only take care of routes after the `hostname` is provided.